# Include words in nltk regular expressions

Tags: python, nltk

NLTK regular expressions work with tags such as:

```
<DT>? <JJ>* <NN>*
```

is there a way to include words within the regex? IE: `"<N> <such> <as> <N> <and> <N>"`

Answer (score 2):

As i remember `<DT>? <JJ>* <NN>*` is a chunk pattern . and the chunk patterns are converted internally to regular expressions using the `tag_pattern2re_pattern()` function:

```
>>> from nltk.chunk import tag_pattern2re_pattern
>>> tag_pattern2re_pattern('<DT>?<NN.*>+')
'(<(DT)>)?(<(NN[^\\{\\}<>]*)>)+'
```

then you could put your words inside the regex pattern result .

Comment: What would an example of including words in NLTK regular expressions  look like?

Comment: @ProfVersaggi What you mean by *including words*?

Comment: Using this question as inspiration: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204968/matching-words-with-nltks-chunk-parser?rq=1

What I'm trying to do is have the NLTK's chunk parser match on a particular word if it finds it in the sentence it's parsing.

For instance, if I am using the following code:

chunkGram = r"""Chunk: {<RB.?>*<VB.?>*<NNP>+<NN>?}"""  

It matches on the corresponding phrase structure when it finds it. What I want to do is have it (additionally) look for an explicit word - like "Bob" and consider matching on that in it's execution.

Comment: @ProfVersaggi did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to convert the tags of the words. Modify the tag of the word you want to use in the regular expression.

Example:

```py
import nltk

pos_tags = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize('Tea such as Green and Brown.'))

# use certain words as it is in grammar
same_word_tags = ['such', 'as', 'and']
pos_tags = [
    (w, w.upper()) if w in same_word_tags else (w, t)
    for w, t in pos_tags
]

grammar = "CHUNK: {<NN.*> <SUCH> <AS> <NN.*> <AND> <NN.*>}"
tree = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar).parse(pos_tags)
```